# VB.net windorms supplier-> Client connections and passing data

Tags: sforce.connection

I am hoping someone can help me. Our client wishes us to connect to Salesforce via API to send data.

The data that they require is in JSON format using the system.web serializer in vb.net framework v4.0 and they are currently reviewing a sample quantity of data before giving us credentials/keys/whatever is required to connect, however, I do not have any idea whatsoever of how this connectivity will be done or what protocols will be used for me to pass the data over to them.

I presume it will be some kind of credentials (am I doing some kind of post using the .net web component and awaiting a reply which will give me a key to then pass to a webpage?) whereabouts I will then be able to send this information over (using what protocol?) and thats as far as we go. We will be doing this some 300 times a month using an automated process.

Not sure what are the standard method(s) available, that a supplier would use to connect to a client's system within SF.
We wont be querying or doing anything other to our client system other than handing over data several times a day. for some reason our client has given us links to pages that look like what THEY would be using to create an account for us, which gives us no indication of how this is all going to be accomplished at our end, as a supplier.

So what I am asking is :
What are the normal protocols that are using to connect and pass a JSON file/string over to salesforce.
What components do we need?
Any examples in vb.net basic sample of connecting with credentials, passing a string over and getting a reply that says data was ok and then we can disconnect.

Thanks and sorry its a bit "muddy" - but you now have as much information as we do.

Carl

Comment: One approach would be to build a custom REST API using Apex.  But if it's as muddy as you say, then you'll need to get more details to understand the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce exposes several APIs, and in pretty much every reasonable circumstance those will be locked behind authentication (which there are several methods of as well).

I've no experience with Microsoft's .net, but my hope here is that by giving you a rundown of the appropriate terminology and general order in which things are done, you'll be able to take it from there.

Without any additional information, I'll assume that your client:

- has set up a "connected app" in Salesforce
- is expecting you to authenticate using an OAuth 2.0 flow
- has created a custom REST resource, the endpoint of which will contain
  `<instance url here>/services/apexrest/<client-controlled path>`

So it should boil down to making a series of HTTP calls to Salesforce.

You'll be making a call (or several, potentially) to authenticate with Salesforce and receive an "access token". After you get the access token, you use it to make the call that you (your client) wants you to make.

#### Authenticating

Salesforce has [resources on the OAuth 2.0 flows that they support](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5). Most of the flows are interactive (i.e. they pop up a screen or window or a modal and require a Salesforce user on your client's side to enter their credentials).

The one flow I'm familiar with that is non-interactive is the [JWT Bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5&language=en_US). Given your description, this is the one I'd expect you'll end up using.

To use the JWT Bearer flow, you'd need the following from your client:

- The "Consumer Key" (also called the "Client Id") from the "Connected App" in your client's Salesforce instance
- The username of an active user in your client's Salesforce instance (with a profile that has the "API Enabled" and "Apex REST Services" system permissions). This will look like an email address
- The public-private keypair (X509 certificate) your client is using in the Connected App for digital signatures

The JWT flow documentation does a fairly good job at explaining what you need to do to manually construct the JWT payload (header and claims). The only real "gotcha" here is that you need to use Base64*Url* encoding instead of normal Base64.

You send the `grant_type=' + 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' + '&assertion=' + <signedJwtRequest here>` in the body of a POST request to `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`
(or `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` if it's a sandbox)

If everything goes well, you'll get a response (JSON by default) containing the access token, an "instance url", and some other bits and bobs.

#### Calling the API

This is the simple part.

It's just another HTTP request using the endpoint that your client configured, which will look like
`<instance url from the OAuth flow>/services/apexrest/<client configured path>`
The instance url will be something like `https://na14.salesforce.com` or `https://my-company.lightning.force.com`

Your client should tell you if you need to GET or POST (I'd expect POST) to that endpoint. From there, you add the appropriate data to the query string and/or body, and send it off.

You are required to set the `Authorization` header to a value of `Bearer <access token here>` (yes, the space between "Bearer" and the access token is necessary)

You'll get an HTTP response code back, with a code of '200' indicating success.

Since it is HTTP, there is nothing to 'disconnect'.